# Zoom jquery with same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want change css on div with jquery when click on div but i have a lot of divs with same class.Beacuse i dynamicly create new divs with php and i cant change their class.

```
<div class="divphoto">
  <img src="photo1.jpg">
</div>

<div class="divphoto">
  <img src="photo2.jpg">
</div>

<div class="divphoto">
  <img src="photo3.jpg">
</div>

<div class="divphoto">
  <img src="photo4.jpg">
</div>

$(".divphoto").click(function(){ 
  $(".divphoto").toggleClass("zoom");           
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this, it choses the specific div that has been clicked on and not all of the .divphoto classes

```
    $(".divphoto").click(function(){ 
      $(this).toggleClass("zoom");           
    });
```